# Starting external application from Powershell under System account

Tags: powershell

I need to execute application which will be running under System user account (powershell itself is running under standard user account with administrator rights). I tried Start-Process cmdlet with custom credentials:

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @("system", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "" -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process -Credential $cred "app.exe"
```

But i have a two problems with that. First I can't create credential object without or with blank password (system user doesn't have any) and when I use credential with just any password I get error message that password is incorrect. Any ideas how to do this?

Btw I can't use psexec for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think itsn't possible with powershell. You can try to use the `at` (dos command):

```
at TIME /interactive app.exe
```

where `TIME` is the hour `hh.mm` when start process...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invoke-TokenManipulation.ps1](https://github.com/clymb3r/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-TokenManipulation/Invoke-TokenManipulation.ps1) script:

> This script requires Administrator privileges. It can enumerate the Logon Tokens available and use them to create new processes. This allows you to use
>   anothers users credentials over the network by creating a process with their logon token. This will work even with Windows 8.1 LSASS protections.

Copy-paste it or save alongside with your script as `Invoke-TokenManipulation.ps1` and use dot-sourcing to load:

```powershell
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. (Join-Path -Path $ScriptDir -ChildPath 'Invoke-TokenManipulation.ps1')
```

And then you can use `Invoke-TokenManipulation` function.

Example:

```powershell
# Spawns cmd.exe as SYSTEM.
Invoke-TokenManipulation -CreateProcess "cmd.exe" -Username "nt authority\system"
```